# Editing info.plist of .ipa files renders app unable to run

Tags: itunes, applications, plist, ios

I'm trying to edit some values of an info.plist file that is located in an .ipa file. First, I open the .ipa in Winrar and drag the info.plist to the desktop. Here, I edit the file using the Properly List Editor that's included on OS X. Finally, I drag the file back into the .ipa, but when I try to sync the file to my iPad, it says that there is an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise, but iOS apps are digitally signed, so editing them in this way is probably evident to the OS because of that, and it doesn't let you run the app.

Comment: Jailbreaking the device may allow you to do this, as it allows for unsigned code to be installed.

Answer (score 4):

Your editing breaks the signature and iOS is designed not to run apps that have been modified. It’s a security feature. A nice explanation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).